# How to invoke a velocityMacro stored in a Velocity template from Java

Tags: java, velocity

I would like to invoke a macro defined in a Velocity template file from my Java application.

For example, I defined the following macro in a template file named `helloworld.vm`:

```
#macro( print $msg $n )
#foreach( $i in [1..$n] )
Hello ${msg}!
#end
#end
```

And then, I would like to use the velocity engine to execute a specific macro:

```
velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", ClassLoaderResourceLoader.class.getName());
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.classloader", this.classLoader);
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.location", "PATH_TO_TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY");
velocityEngine.init();

velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

velocityContext.put("msg", "Tom");
velocityContext.put("n", 2);
velocityEngine.invokeVelocimacro("print", "print", new String[]{"msg","n"}, velocityContext, sw);
```

Which I would expect to feed `sw` with something like:

```
Hello Tom!
Hello Tom!
```

But rather produces the following error:

```
RuntimeInstance.invokeVelocimacro() : VM 'print' is not registered.
```

Therefore, what is the procedure for registering a velocityMacro or is there any other way of invoking a Velocity macro stored in a custom template file from Java?

Comment: I don't believe any templates will have been loaded yet, no?

Comment: Should I explicitly load the `helloworld.vm` template using `velocityEngine.getTemplate("helloworld.vm")`?

Comment: Could try it; I'm not sure--never tried to do what you're doing.

Comment: Cool :) Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to also specify the property `resource.loader=class` in order for Velocity to use the classloader-based loader.

See the [`ClasspathResourceLoader` javadocs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ClasspathResourceLoader.html).

In addition, is this template file actually on the classpath?

Comment: I already use the `ClasspathResourceLoader` and the template is part of the classpath.